# kubectl exec fails while kubectl logs works

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

This reliably fails for me:

`$ kubectl --namespace=blah exec -t -i infra-web-2181569391-65mtk -c apache bash
Error from server: ssh: rejected: connect failed (Connection timed out)`

while this reliably works, proving that master-node connectivity is OK:

`$ kubectl --namespace=blah logs infra-web-2181569391-65mtk -c apache 
[some messages from apache]`

What could be the reason?

BTW, using `ls` in place of `bash` has the same result.

Comment: How did you provision your cluster?

Comment: By clicking "Create" in the console. I did have some firewall problems, could  one of the gke-* firewall rules missing have such consequences (exec failing but logs working at the same time)? I reinstated the -ssh rule, but did not know about the other ones until I created another cluster.

Comment: I thought that both exec and logs went through the same path (which requires the firewall rules to be in place) but it sounds like you just gather empirical evidence that I was incorrect. Did creating a new cluster with the expected firewall rules solve your problem?

Comment: Apparently yes. AFAICT the firewall rules for the new cluster were not deleted by our automation, so this could have been it. However there were more differences, for example I upgraded the old cluster, and the new one was created already using version 1.3.2.

Comment: When you create a new cluster, it will be created at the default version of Kubernetes that is supported by GKE. [v1.3.2](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md/#v132) fixed a number of critical bugs running Kubernetes on GCE.

Comment: I understand that, I'm just saying that the difference in the firewall rules was not the only difference between the clusters.

Comment: That's certainly true, but not being able to kubectl exec strongly points towards the firewall rules being the difference that caused the problem.